# How to find similar sequences between two texts in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, similarity

I'm trying to compare two different texts to store similar sequences. However, I struggle to figure out a way to do it. What I'm looking for is something like this:

Let's say we have two texts:

Text 1:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est here."

Text 2:
"Hi, I'm looking for a course to learn programming. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat idk what I'm supposed to write down here."

I want to get the similar sequences in the both texts. In this case it is:

"Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."

But there are two rules:

1 - Similarities should be consisting of groups of sentences (so they have to make at least one sentence); anything that does not make a full sentence should be ignored.

For example, this should be stored: "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."

But not the three-word sequence coming right after it: "Excepteur sint occaecat"

2 - Everyday expressions should be ignored. (ex: "Hope to hear from you soon", "God bless you", etc.)

How can I program this algorithm, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
//You can add more expressions
const everyday_expressions = ["Hello.", "Hope to hear from you soon", "God bless you"];

const text1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est here.";
const text2 = "Hi, I'm looking for a course to learn programming. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat idk what I'm supposed to write down here.";

const arr_text1 = text1.split(".").map(val=>val.trim()+".");
const arr_text2 = text2.split(".").map(val=>val.trim()+".");

const result = arr_text1.filter(val => (val.length > 1 && arr_text2.indexOf(val) > -1) && everyday_expressions.indexOf(val) == -1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important, consider using binary search:

```js
const commonExpressions = [
  'hope to hear from you soon',
  'god bless you',
  'see you tomorrow',
  /* ... */
];

commonExpressions.sort(); // or store them sorted

function binarySearch(arr, str) {
  let low = 0, high = arr.length - 1;
  while (low <= high) {
    const mid = Math.floor((low + high) / 2);
    const c = arr[mid].localeCompare(str);
    if (c < 0) low = mid + 1;
    else if (c > 0) high = mid - 1;
    else return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function findSimilarities(text1, text2) {
  const rawSentences1 = text1.split('.').map(s => s.trim());
  const sentences1 = rawSentences1
    .map(s => s.toLowerCase())
    .filter(s => s && !binarySearch(commonExpressions, s));

  const sentences2 = text2
    .split('.')
    .map(s => s.trim().toLowerCase())
    .filter(s => s && !binarySearch(commonExpressions, s));
  sentences2.sort();

  let result = sentences1.reduce((matches, s, i) => {
    if (binarySearch(sentences2, s)) {
      matches.push(i);
    }
    return matches;
  }, []).map(i => rawSentences1[i]).join('. ');

  return result && result + '.';
}

let text1 = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est here.`;

let text2 = `Hi, I'm looking for a course to learn programming. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat idk what I'm supposed to write down here.`;

console.log(findSimilarities(text1, text2));
```

I assume here that you want case insensitive comparison of sentences, so I use `toLowerCase()`.

Note that this solution is asymmetric, i.e. swapping the arguments could lead to a different result. The following could be the reason:

1. Because of the case insensitive comparison, matching sentences do not have to be strictly equal. In this case, the capitalization from the first text is the one used in the result string. That is also the reason we store the sentences from the first text with the original capitalization in `rawSentences1`. If we did not, the result string would be in lower case.
2. The matching sentences come up in the result string in the order they have in the first text. They could have a different order in the second text and still be considered a match. If, instead, you want to get as many matching sentences as possible so that they come up in the *same* order in both texts, you should read about the [longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).